# Nginx, exception in rewrite rule

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I am stuck with a specific server configuration.

- I have a domain: **www.domain.com**.
- I redirect mobiles users to **m.domain.com**

Until now, no problem.

I want to **do not redirect** mobile users to m.domain.com on a specific page.

This is what I have now:

```
if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) {
    rewrite ^ http://m.domain.com redirect;
    break;
}
```

I want something like (pseudo code):

```
if ($mobile_rewrite = perform && Location != /path/* ) {
    rewrite ^ http://m.domain.com redirect;
    break;
}
```

Thank you for your tips!

Answer (score 1):

I actually found something using the **$request** var:

```
set $mobile_rewrite = [...] (perform or do_not_perferm)
if ($request ~* "path") {
    set $mobile_rewrite do_not_perform;
}
if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) {
    rewrite ^ http://m.domain.com redirect;
    break;
}
```

Maybe not the best solution, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($request_uri !~ "^/blog/\w+$")
 { 
   set $mobile_rewrite do_not_perform;
 }
```

and i think this work.